# How to show dropdowns with selected options if form is submitted and have validation errors

Tags: php, jquery, validation, submit, show

I have a form with radio buttons first. When you choose a radio button, it is shown different dropdowns for different radio buttons. They are dependent dropdowns. First I hide them all. It's working, but when you click submit button and there are fields or options that you have not filled, these dropdowns hide and you have to select them again. 
I want to make if you click submit button and there are validation errors, to show these dropdowns for the radio, you have chosen, and your choices to be selected.
Here's my code:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
              $(":radio").click(function(){
                  $('#region').val('Choose region');
                  $('#school').val('Choose region');
                  $('#teacher').val('Choose school');
                  $('#class').val('Choose class');
                  $('#class_divisions').val('Choose division');
              });
          });

              function showHide(self, show){

                  $(".all_teachers_show, .toggle, .school,  .teacher_school, .teacher, .class, .teacher_class").hide();
         
                  if (show)
                      $('.toggle').show();
                  else
                      $('.toggle').hide();
                  $(":radio").prop('checked',false);
                  $(self).prop('checked',true);
              }
              
              function show(yes, no){
                  if (no)
                      $('.school').show();
                  else
                      $('.school').hide();
                  $("region").prop('checked',false);
                  $(yes).prop('checked',true);
              }
              
              function school_show(yes, no){
          
                if(document.getElementById("radio1").checked===true){
                   document.getElementById('class_label').innerHTML = 'Class:*';
                  if (no)
                        $('.teacher').show();
                    else
                        $('.teacher').hide();
                    $("school").prop('checked',false);
                    $(yes).prop('checked',true);
                }
               
                if(document.getElementById("radio2").checked===true){
                    document.getElementById('class_label').innerHTML = 'Class teacher:*';
                  if (no)
                      $('.class').show();
                  else
                      $('.class').hide();
                  $("school").prop('checked',false);
                  $(yes).prop('checked',true);

                }
              }
             
              function class_show(yes, no){
              
                if (no)
                      $('.class').show();
                  else
                      $('.class').hide();
                  $("teacher").prop('checked',false);
                  $(yes).prop('checked',true);
              
              }
              
              function teachers_show(yes, no){
                $(".toggle, .all_teachers_show,  .school,  .teacher_school, .teacher, .class, .teacher_class").hide();
                  if (no)
                      $('.all_teachers_show').show();
                  else
                      $('.all_teachers_show').hide();
                  $(":radio").prop('checked',false);
                  $(yes).prop('checked',true);
              }
               
          </script>   
          <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#region').change(function() {
                        var url = "<?= base_url() ?>index.php/home/get_schools";
                        var postdata = {region: $('#region').val()};
                        $.post(url, postdata, function(result) {
                            var $school_sel = $('#school');
                            $school_sel.empty();
                            $school_sel.append("<option>Choose region</option>");
                            var schools_obj = JSON.parse(result);
                            $.each(schools_obj, function(key, val) {
                                var option = '<option  value="' + val.school_id + '">' + val.school_name + '</option>';
                                $school_sel.append(option);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
          </script>  
          <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#school').change(function() {
                        var url = "<?= base_url() ?>index.php/home/get_teachers";
                        var postdata = {school: $('#school').val()};
                        $.post(url, postdata, function(result) {
                            var $teacher_sel = $('#teacher');
                            $teacher_sel.empty();
                            $teacher_sel.append("<option>Choose school</option>");
                            var teachers_obj = JSON.parse(result);
                            $.each(teachers_obj, function(key, val) {
                                var option = '<option value="' + val.user_id + '">' + val.username + '</option>';
                                $teacher_sel.append(option);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
```

```html
<?php
          
          echo validation_errors();
          echo "<div class='container'>";
          echo form_open();
        echo "<table border = '0' >";
          echo "<tr><td><label>  Username:* </label></td><td>";
          $data=array(
            'name' => 'username',
            'class' => form_error('username') ? 'error' : '',
            'value' => set_value('username')
          );
          echo form_input($data);
          echo "</td></tr>";
          echo "<tr><td><label> Password:* </label></td><td>";
          $data=array(
            'name' => 'password',
            'class' => form_error('password') ? 'error' : ''
          );
          echo form_password($data);
         echo "<tr><td><label>  Choose role:* </label> </td><td>";
        <input type="radio" name="role_id" onClick='showHide(this, true)' id="radio1"  <?php echo set_radio('role_id', '1'); ?> />
         <?php echo " Student ";
        $data=array(
            'name' => 'role_id',
            'value' => set_value('role_id', '2'),
            'id' => 'radio2',
            'onclick' => 'showHide(this, true)'
            );
          echo form_radio($data);
          echo " Teacher ";

          $data=array(
            'name' => 'role_id',
            'value' => set_value('role_id', '5'),
            'id' => 'radio5',
            'onclick' => 'teachers_show(this, true)'
            );
          echo form_radio($data);
          echo " Coord. ";
          echo "</td></tr>";
          echo "<tr class='toggle' style='display:none;' ><td><label>  Region:*  </label></td><td>";
          ?>
        <select name='region'   id='region' onChange='show(this, true)'>
          <option <?php echo set_select('region'); ?>>Choose region</option>
              <?php foreach ($regions as $row) { ?>
                <option name='region' value= "<?= $row->region ?>"><?= $row->region ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
          </select> 
          <?php
          echo "</td></tr>";

          echo "<tr class='school' style='display:none;' ><td><label> School:*  
          </label></td><td>";  
          ?>
        <select id="school" name="school[]"  onChange='school_show(this, true)'>
         <option <?php echo set_select('school[]'); ?>>Choose region</option>
          </select>
          <?php echo "</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr class='teacher' style='display:none;' onChange='class_show(this, true)'><td><label>  Teacher:* 
          </label> </td><td>";
          
          echo '<select id="teacher"  name="teacher[]">';
          ?>
          <option <?php echo set_select('teacher'); ?>>Choose school</option>
          </select>  
          </td></tr>
        <?php
          echo "<tr class='class'  style='display:none;'><td>  <label  id='class_label'> Клас:* </label> </td><td>";

          ?>
           <select name='class[]'  id='class'>
           <option <?php echo set_select('class[]'); ?>>Choose class</option>
              <?php foreach ($classes as $row) { ?>
                <option value= "<?= $row->id ?>"><?= $row->class_id ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
          </select> 
         
           <select name='class_divisions[]'  id='class_divisions'>
            <option <?php echo set_select('class_divisions[]'); ?>>Choose division</option>
            <?php foreach ($class_divisions as $row) { ?>
         <option value= "<?= $row->id ?>"><?= $row->division ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
          </select>   
          </td></tr>

          <?php
          echo "<tr class='all_teachers_show' style='display:none;'><td><label>  Teachers:*  </label></td><td>";
          ?>
         
          <?php foreach ($all_teachers_show as $row) { ?>
         
          <input type="checkbox" id='all_teachers_show' <?php echo set_checkbox('all_teachers_show[]'); ?> name="all_teachers_show[]"
           value="<?= $row->user_id ?>"><?= $row->username ?>
              <?php } 

          echo "</td></tr>";
          echo "</div>";
          echo "</table><br/>";
        $data=array(
            "name" => 'mysubmit',
            'class' => 'btn btn-success ',
            'id' => 'reg',
            'value' => 'Register'
          );
          echo form_submit($data);
          ?>
          </form>
​
```

Comment: Please have mercy for our eyes, this code is totally unreadable, I began to improve it, but I didn't have to courage to finish

Comment: Sorry for that,I can try to do it myself, but could you  tell me the idea how to show dropdowns with selected options when form is submitted? :)